# Php - echo a MySQL result as geojson

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, leaflet, geojson

I have a table in a MySQL db, that has a geometry field (polygon)

Now I can query the geometry field and get a geojson like this:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(b.shape) FROM `tbl_polygon` as b where ST_Intersects(b.shape, ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((28.0921 -26.11351,28.09210 -26.11288,28.0929502 -26.1128831,28.092950 -26.113510,28.0921027 -26.113510))',1))
```

In MySQL I get a geojson as a result:

```
{"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[28.092521118...
```

Now here is where I'm getting stuck, I have a leafletjs map and want to display this geojson as layer.

So how can I, from an external php file, echo the geojson so that I can get the geojson into my javascript and use Leaflet's L.geoJSON to add the layer.

I'm not sure if this will even work this way.
Any advice will be great.
Thanks,

Based on Majid Abbasi's great answer( thanks). I tried it, But clearly I'm missing something I just get a blank page with no errors. Thanks Majid.
Here is the code from my index.php file:

**Index.php**

```
<?php
require_once(conn.php);
$myquery = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(b.shape) FROM `tbl_polygon` as b where ST_Intersects(b.shape, ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((28.092102706432343 -26.113510096462498,28.092102706432343 -26.11288390575381,28.092950284481045 -26.11288390575381,28.092950284481045 -26.113510096462498,28.092102706432343 -26.113510096462498))',1))";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $myquery);?>
```

`<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>`

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([28.092102706432343, -26.113510096462498], 13); 

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
        '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
        'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap);  

var data = <?php echo $result; ?>
 ployLayer = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a JavaScript variable in your PHP file like this, and call initializeMap function that create your map and pass the data to that:

```
<?php
require_once(conn.php);
$myquery = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(b.shape) as jsonData FROM `tbl_polygon` as b where ST_Intersects(b.shape, ST_GeomFromText('Polygon((28.092102706432343 -26.113510096462498,28.092102706432343 -26.11288390575381,28.092950284481045 -26.11288390575381,28.092950284481045 -26.113510096462498,28.092102706432343 -26.113510096462498))',1))";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $myquery);
$data = mysqli_fetch_fields(result);
$ST_AsGeoJSON = $data->jsonData;
?>
<script language="javascript">
    var data = <?php echo $ST_AsGeoJSON; ?>;
</script>
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([28.092102706432343, -26.113510096462498], 13); 

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
    '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
    'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
id: 'mapbox.streets'
}).addTo(mymap); 
ployLayer = L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
```

Be aware you should run your query and get data and put those on $ST_AsGeoJSON before of this script.

and should have initializeMap method in your javascript that create map.

Comment: Thanks Majid, this might just work for me. I tried to implement it but I'm getting some issues, if you get some time can you please have a look at the edit I made to my question. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks this is fantastic. Thanks again